# Global variable in dynamic library

Tags: c, global

I have created a dynamic library in C. This library uses a global variable like `static int a=1`. 
Now I am using this library in my app. On compiling, the compiler produces an error "undefined reference to a".

What would cause this?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90530

Answer (score 3):

`static` for a global variable makes that variable only available in that compilation unit. In other words, a global `static int a;` will not be visible outside the library.

Drop the `static` if you want to allow library users to access it.